# Compute and return value on event handler function

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I am looking to store a returned value to a variable from the event handler function.

Here is the example code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    function getData(e){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                e = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                return e;   
            }
            else{
                return alert("Error!!");
            }
        }
    }
      
   var data;
   xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){getData(data);},true);  // want to store the result to data variable
   console.log(data);
```

Comment: You can in fact return a value from `getData`, however it is impossible to return that value to the outer scope because the outerscope has already returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    //function to return your value function(xhr.responseText)
}
};
```